# Copying specifig files from multiple folders to one target folder?

Tags: command-line, directory, copy

Is it possible to use `mv` or `cp` commands to collect all photos from multiple subfolders to target folder `rec_all` via one command in terminal?

I have about 400 subfolders! Each of them have hundreds of photos like .jpg! Subfolders names are `rec_pho.1` to `rec_pho.400`.
Target folder is `rec_all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yeah, (your syntax will depend though) :

```
cp -r Pictures/rec_pho.*/*.jpg Pictures/rec_all/
```

Comment: Do you need the `-rf` flags?

Comment: I'm just thinking is it necessary and I'm testing this command: cp Pictures/rec_pho.*/*.jpg Pictures/rec_all/

Comment: I just checked destination folder "rec_all" from nautilus and it looks that it works!  Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @wjandrea `-r` is for recursive usefull in this case. when I tested in on a couple folders with logs, some had the same name, so `-f` made it so that the new copied files would crush the older. this is at the user's discretion, personally I prefer ham-fisted approaches to these sort of problems. considering cameras generally put the date and time in the picture's name this would fuze them. I removed the `-f` as I can see why this could be quote-unquote dangerous.

Comment: @Jari if this worked for you, could you mark as answer and upvote please?

Comment: @tatsu We need `-r`  for copying directories, but in this case we're copying files.

Comment: @wjandrea fair enough, it can serve as a failsafe though. maybe the user did know pre-emptively about that one subdirrectory that was the exception to the rule?

Comment: @tatsu I don't follow. How is it a failsafe? (not saying you're wrong, just I'm confused)

Comment: Hi, the process is done!  There is over 29000 files in destination folder! Thank You Very Much :)

Answer (score 3):

use the `-t` option

```sh
cd /root/directory/for/photos
# mv -t /destination/directory */*.jpg
cp -t /destination/directory */*.jpg
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mv.1.html
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: oh! better than mine, have an upvote! (issue is you should make a backup of folder first if preserving the hiarchy is of any use later)

Comment: Just to be extra clear, for OP's case it would be `cp -t rec_all rec_pho.*/*.jpg`